# What will happen to already installed application after code signing certificate expires?

Tags: code-signing-certificate

We have distributed various applications exes, windows services and asp.net mvc web applications to our clients. All these applications and there dependent dlls' code were signed with certificate, but we missed to timestamp it.
Now the certificate is going to expire, and we are afraid what would be its affect on clients?
I have checked various other threads on internet regarding this, and it seems that there would be no effect on already installed applications, as the certificate is being checked on first run of the application. But I am not sure what will happen to exes.
Will the client still be able to launch exe after expiration of certificate?

Comment: Maybe you can simulate what will happen by changing the date for one computer where the app is installed...

Comment: Thanks Angel! I have tried to it by changing the date of computer and app is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless revoked, the application will still run because at the moment of signing, the certificate was good.

The purpose of signing the binaries is to be able to always verify that your binary is not tampered with, that is, nobody altered your publication ever.